# EXC Bad Access on Button Click

Tags: xcode, memory-management, exc-bad-access

Thoroughly stumped. 
I open an action sheet with a view controller in it, and when I click a button in the view controller to launch an SLComposeViewController, I get the error.

This is how I initialize the action sheet with the view controller in it:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil

                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"1",@"2",nil];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 285)];
ExportVC*innerView = [[ExportVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExportVC" bundle:nil];
innerView.view.frame = actionSheet.bounds;
[actionSheet addSubview:innerView.view];

[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

This is the ExportVC.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>


@interface ExportVC : UIViewController{
}

- (IBAction)tweet:(id)sender;


@end
```

And here's the ExportVC.m file, where the IBAction launches the SLComposeViewController:

```
#import "ExportVC.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>


@interface ExportVC ()

@end

@implementation ExportVC



-(IBAction)tweet:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"button works");
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController* tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                           composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Hi"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

The connections are fine. I don't have anything in the viewdidload of the ExportVC. Whenever I click the button attached to the "tweet" action however, I get the EXC Bad Access error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that I have had before as well. It has to do with the way that ARC releases memory.

When you are creating your `ExportVC` object and adding it to the actionSheet, as soon as the method is terminated, although the view is added to the actionSheet, there is no reference to the viewController. Because of this, the viewController is destroyed due to having a retain count of 0, and when you fire the `tweet:(id)sender` method, the viewController with the method no longer exists, hence  you get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

The way I have been able to fix this is by creating a reference to the viewController that I am making in the class that creates the alertSheet and setting it to the viewController so that it does not get released.

Comment: in the .h file of the viewController that creates the actionSheet, you can add something along the lines of: `@property (nonatomic, strong) ExportVC *exportView`, and then when you create the actionSheet do: `self.exportView = innerView`.

Comment: Ya its annoying to have to do that but at least it works. You also might want to set that variable to `nil` when the actionSheet is released so that it releases the memory. When I first had this problem a few months ago, it took me a few days to figure out what was going on.